# Add bulk item to list data doesn't update the recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have method like this to initialize a recyclerview:

```
private void getSuratList() {
    SuratService suratService = ServiceGeneratorUtils.createService(SuratService.class);
    Call<SuratList> suratListCall = suratService.getListSurat(user.getId());
    suratListCall.enqueue(new Callback<SuratList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<SuratList> call, @NonNull Response<SuratList> response) {
            mSuratList = new ArrayList<>();
            mSuratList.addAll(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getData());
            mMainAdapter.edit().replaceAll(mSuratList).commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<SuratList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

and whenever it reach the end of item, it should load more item, and this code for load more data from api:

```
    mActivityHomeBinding.activityMainRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListenerUtils() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(RecyclerView recyclerView, int currentPage) {
            SuratService suratService = ServiceGeneratorUtils.createService(SuratService.class);
            Call<SuratList> suratListNextCall = suratService.getListSuratNextPage(user.getId(), Integer.valueOf(currentPage).longValue());
            suratListNextCall.enqueue(new Callback<SuratList>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<SuratList> call, @NonNull Response<SuratList> response) {
                    mSuratList.addAll(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getData());
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<SuratList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't update the adapter

Comment: Why don't you call `mMainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. You should check `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`, what is recyclerView here?

Comment: I've tried them both all but it still doesn't affect anything.